# how the get selected value of dynamically added option

Tags: jquery, ajax

The options below are added dynamically by an ajax call. Now I want to get the selected value and use it further.

```
<select class="form-control" name="product" id="product">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">sku_MOTOE</option>//added dynamically
    <option value="2">sku_C</option>//added dynamically
    <option value="3">sku_S2</option>//added dynamically
    <option value="4">sku_S5</option>//added dynamically
</select>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#product").load("/bin/getcontent?type=options"); 
    console.log($("#product option:selected").val());//null
});
```

Comment: You want default selected value or get selected value each time user selects one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, `.load()` is an asynchronous function call. Statements following the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete) method are execute immediately thus you are getting `null`

You need to use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete)'s complete callback method

> A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

*Script*

```
 $("#product").load("/bin/getcontent?type=options", function(){
    console.log($("#product option:selected").val());
    //Or, console.log($("#product").val());
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the load to complete:

```
$(function() {
    $("#product").load("/bin/getcontent?type=options", function() { 
        console.log($("#product option:selected").val());
    });
});
```

[load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous so the next line of code (console.log) runs before the load has finished loading the options.

You can pass a function/callback to the "complete" parameter of load and that will be called when the load has finished loading.

Comment: just realized it was silly question. Anyways thanks.